# iOS 14 AssistiveTouch Dwell Control sometimes not working on SwiftUI Buttons

Tags: swiftui, ios14, assistive

I have a SwiftUI App which uses regular `Button` views and our customers use AssistiveTouch's DwellControl feature quite often. On iOS 13 DwellControl was working fine but on iOS 14 beta 8 DwellControl fails to be able click on those buttons.

The Buttons can be tapped by finger and clicked with the normal mouse but not with the DwellControl feature.

I have tried adding accessibility traits like `isButton`, but nothing works.

Has anyone encountered the same problem and has a solution or any insight at all? I know this is quite niche but any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

I have tested it with a very simple example, including one a Button and it works fine. It seems to be a side effect of some sorts in my specific App.

I have several `ZStack`s which show and hide some views like modals and popovers. Could this be the source of failure?

What I don't get is that the `Button`s can be tapped and clicked... If a view was blocking the `Button` then this shouldn't be possible right?

I have tried `Release` and `Debug` builds which does not make a difference.

When DwellControl is activated and the cursor is on the `Button` that shall be clicked, tapping doesn't work either. But when the cursor is nowhere near the `Button`, tapping works fine.

I have send a report via Feedback to Apple.

EDIT:

I found the cause. ScrollView somehow prevents all DwellControl clicks from happening. That happens whenever a ScrollView is somewhere present in one of the Views.

Minimal example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                Button(action: {
                    print("This should be printed but isn't....")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Button in ScrollView")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know its niche but maybe someone needs this.

There are other components which are affected and cause the same behaviour:

- `ScrollView`
- `TextField`
- `Slider`
- `Stepper`
- `UIViewRepresentable`

For me this is a big issue, since our customers use DwellControl quite often.

EDIT:

This can be replicated in the newest iOS 14.2 beta 1:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TempSwitUIApp: App {
    @State private var text: String = "I am a text"
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
                Button(action: {
                    print("\(UUID()) \(self.text)")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Print text to the console")
                })
            TextField("Hello", text: self.$text)
        }
    }
}
```

I updated my issue with Apple but haven't heard from them yet.